Test a @Async annotated method without waiting for completion
I have the following method annotated with @Async
@Async(DefaultNameExtension.DEFAULT_SECURITY_THREAD_ASYNC)
public Boolean sincronizzazioneDatiPreliminari(Integer campagna) throws Exception{
   ...
}

I would like to create a JUnit method that tests the asynchronicity of the method, that is, once invoked, while it is still running, it does something that certifies the asynchronicity.
I'm using Spring Boot.
I tried searching on the internet but the solutions I found all wait for the method to finish its execution.

You may check the active thread count with Thread.activeCount(). Do not forget to give a short sleep (e.g., Thread.sleep(100)) to give the asynchronous method time to start a new thread before verifying.

Checkout awaitility it should suit your usecase.
https://github.com/awaitility/awaitility
